# Loss of the precision information of a number on Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Consider following simplified example:

```
create view viewa as select cast(1 as decimal(3)) as testa from dual;
create view viewb as
  with sorted as (select testa from viewa order by testa)
  select testa from sorted;
desc viewb;
```

On Oracle 11g this example prints following as expected:

```
Name  Null Type      
----- ---- --------- 
TESTA      NUMBER(3)
```

But on Oracle 10g, following is printed:

```
Name  Null Type   
----- ---- ------ 
TESTA      NUMBER
```

I'm puzzled - Why? Is this a bug or is there some explanation for it? If I remove anything, the order by, the common table expression, the other view, the result appears correctly as `NUMBER(3)`. Sure I could recast the result to correct type, but I'd prefer to rely on the database to carry the correct type.

The exact version of the 10g database is `Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0`. Also reproduced on `Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0`.

EDIT: Edited the example to use `select testa` as per the first comment.

Comment: Although handy, `SELECT *` is supposed to be bad for production code. Does it make any difference if you change it to `SELECT testa` ?

Comment: No `select *` can be freely interchanged with `select testa`, and other way round, in the CTE and the very last select.

Comment: I very clearly remember how this changed to the current state about 12 years ago with the upgrade to Oracle 9i, but the reasoning behind the change has faded from my memory.

Comment: Ahah, okay. Good to know I'm not the only one with this problem. Thanks for the info.